# Can't Boot to Windows 8 before or after factory reset

Tags: windows-8, boot, laptop

I have a Toshiba S55 laptop, running Windows 8.1(It came preloaded with windows 8). A few days ago when I switched it on, it hung up and as I was in a hurry, I forced closed it down.

Since then whenever I try to switch it on, It displays the toshiba logo with the circle animation and remains stuck on that screen.

I folllowed various instructions on numerous sites and tried everything from repairing the EFI Bootloader(i.e running the bcdboot commands)(I suspected that because many people who had these symptoms had this problem) to even going as far as resetting the pc.

I could never run BCDEdit as it always gave an error
Also whenever I tried to see the attributes of the fat32 partition, it always said volume service not running..

I could never get it to refresh(Drive is locked) or was able to successfully run the following command

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Even after resetting the laptop, whenever I switch it on, it shows the logo(toshiba), goes to a screen, Loading files, the progress bar completes and back to the logo screen....

Any Suggestions??

Comment: If you've done a factory restore and it still isn't working then it may be the hard disk having errors. If the laptop is still under warranty send it in for a warranty repair. You'll lose all your data but they should fix it.

Comment: already lost all my data. and no longer in warranty. expired a month ago.

Comment: Ouch. Did you create the backup media (http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/System-Recovery-and-Recovery/Creating-Recovery-Media-for-Windows-8/ta-p/353090)?

Comment: ya created the backup media but that didnt help. had to get a new copy of windows and install it via csm, as uefi refused to read it. now am able to boot into windows but only in csm mode.

Answer (score 0):

There are rescue disks based on various versions of Linux, such as Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD) at http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/ultimate_boot_cd_%28ubcd%29.html, designed to help with such issues. You might also create a live Linux USB drive, e.g. Ubuntu, on another machine. In either case, in UEFI (BIOS) setup, enable legacy boot, no security, set USB first in boot order. If you can boot from that USB, then you can at least mount and examine your HDD, and see if there are issues there. At the very worst, you could actually install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or other Linux OS, either dual boot or alone, but permanent installation could cause further problems in recovering any data from the disk.

BTW, the free Macrium Reflect and Drive Image XML offer the ability to make a recovery disk using WinPE and/or Linux; in the future you might want to make a drive image and repair media after buying a new PC, and **update the image before each MS Windows update** - recent Microsoft updates have made some systems unusable.